# How to implement JoinTo efficiently?

Tags: list-manipulation

AppendTo is not efficient so I'm not quite sure of the best way to implement its analogue for joining (e.g. in python this would be extend function). So how can this be improved:

```
ClearAll[JoinTo];
SetAttributes[JoinTo,HoldFirst];
JoinTo[a_, b_List] := (a = Join[a,b];)
```

Comment: need to account for cases where e.g. a is an integer or has some other head

Comment: This will also make a copy of whatever it is replacing, hence will be inefficient if used in a loop. You might consider nesting `List`, as in `a={a,b}` or maybe use of `Reap[...Sow[a]...]`, depending on what is the application at hand.

Comment: Shouldn't using an association be efficient (at least if beforehand the size of `Join[a,b]` were known so that values had just to be updated instead of inserted)? `AssociateTo` at least claims to offer efficient in place modification.

Comment: @Sascha Maybe...Depends on how many `AssociateTo` operations are done, and there may be an ordering issue (I think new things get added at the back and not the front). I'm not sure what algorithmic complexity to expect for adding new items; might be O(log n) for n=length of the association (which of course is much better than O(n)). Best I can suggest is that this approach be tried and timed.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau, I probably should have written my comment more clearly to convey that it contains two separate ideas: **(1)** updating values of associations instead of adding key-value pairs might be efficient (one could create an association with "empty" key-value pairs and update values as necessary; call it pre allocation if you will). **(2)** Just try out the build-in function `AssociateTo` to add key-value pairs and compare with list operations.

Comment: Consider using a linked list and then flattening. You may either do this explicitly at the top level, or else use `Internal\`Bag` and friends. The latter are employed by `Sow` and `Reap`. By the way, it would be helpful if you could state clearly in what respects you would like your idea to be improved upon.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Does Mathematica have linked lists?

Comment: @M.R. Yes, of course. Well, it has lists, and you can link them, so that's sufficient. See for example [(25474)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24988/can-one-identify-the-design-patterns-of-mathematica/25474#25474)

Comment: Oh right, thought they might have added as a first class symbol

Answer (score 4):

We can also use `ApplyTo` (new in 12.2) together with `Splice` (new in 12.1):

```
a = Range[5];
a //= Append[Splice @ Range[6, 10]];
a
```

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

It is fast:

```
a = Range[10^6];
a //= Append[Splice @ Range[10^6]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

0.06516

and can be packed into a function:

```
Attributes[joinTo] = HoldFirst;
joinTo[a_, b_] := a //= Append[Splice @ b]

a = Range[10^6];
joinTo[a, Range[10^6]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

0.062041

```
a // Length
```

2000000

Answer (score 3):

Mapping `AppendTo` over the list of items to append escapes the copy inefficiency.

```
a = Range[5];
AppendTo[a, #] & /@ Range[6, 10];

a
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)
```

**Update with function**

```
ClearAll[joinTo]
Attributes[joinTo] = {HoldFirst};
joinTo[s_Symbol, items_List] := Last@(AppendTo[s, #] & /@ items)

joinTo[a,Range[11,15]]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15} *)
```

Hope this helps.

**Update 2: Benchmarks**

With `joinTo` in this post:

```
a = Range[10000];
joinTo[a, Range[10000]] // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.837118 *)
```

With `JoinTo` (the OP's version):

```
ClearAll[JoinTo];
SetAttributes[JoinTo, HoldFirst];
JoinTo[a_, b_List] := (a = Join[a, b];)

b = Range[10000];
JoinTo[b, Range[10000]] // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.000032 *)
```

To check if the codes are doing the same thing:

```
a == b
(* True *)
```

Comment: I don't usually add benchmarks to people's answers unasked, but in this case I felt that it was important. When you use `Join` you only create one copy, regardless of the length of the list. When you use `AppendTo` the way that you do, you create `n` copies when appending a list of length `n`.

Comment: @Pickett Oh, I thought `AppendTo` was not making a copy but adding to the original list. Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: @Pickett You have shown it is much slower. How would you demonstrate that it is using more memory?

Comment: `MaxMemoryUsed` indicates that it is *not* using more memory, however the efficiency that M.R. and Daniel (in his comment) are talking about is not memory efficiency but how fast the computation runs in a loop. What we see here is exactly why it is common to hear that one should avoid `AppendTo` in favor of, for example, `Sow`/`Reap`, or linked lists.

Comment: @Pickett I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Allow to join more than two lists (double underscore behind `b`)

```
ClearAll[JoinTo, a, b];
SetAttributes[JoinTo, HoldFirst];
JoinTo[a_, b__List] := (a = Join[a, b];)

a = {1, 2};

JoinTo[a, Range@3, {99}]

a
```

> {1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 99}

Comment: this fails if e.g. `a=1` or `a=f[1,2,3]`

Comment: Yes, and it should fail - Try `Join[1, {1, 2}]`

Comment: that was my point. join requires lists. the definition in the post does not confine a to a particular head therefore implies joining heads other than lists. AppendTo allows you to add an integer to a list, so mixed heads ...and so on

Comment: This doesn't address the comment from Daniel on the copy inefficiency, any ideas?

Comment: @M.R. The copy inefficiency is inherent to the concept of `JoinTo`, not a particular implementation of it.